# Group data with two variables

Tags: matlab, statistics

I have a large data set with two variables, `HS` and `Tp`. I like to group these in MATLAB and see how many times one specific value of `HS` and one specific value of `Tp` occurs.

Any ideas?

Comment: Give some examples and your expected result. I don't quite get what you mean.

Answer (score -1):

use `unique` with `'rows'` argument

```
u = unique( [HS(:) Tp(:)], 'rows' );
```

Comment: That doesn't do the counting yet.

Comment: @Jonas you can use the other outout arguments of `unique` to do the actual counting. I'm usually against "spelling it all out" for people who hardly bother to phrase their questions properly.

Comment: Maybe you could link to a question where the counting is done. (the -1 is not mine, though).